# VSTO Winform doesn't appear same time with Excel

Tags: excel, vsto

I create a VSTO application that runs on Excel, but when I click the box, this window is behind excel, is there a way for this form to appear in the excel background?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jISh1.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sf7DP.png)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you pass the right window parent (`IWin32Window`) when you call `Form.Show` or `Form.ShowDialog`. You can create a new `Win32Window` class and pass the right `HWMD` to its constructor: under 32 bit, use `Window.Hwnd` property. Under 64 bit, use `GetActiveWindow` Windows API function (since `Window.Hwnd` is broken in 64 bit - the property is 4 bytes, not 8).

Comment: Can you give specific instructions?